# ViewFlipper 3D-Card-Flip

Tags: android, animation, clone, viewflipper

I started a new Android-App and I have one problem.

I want to code a ViewFlipper within some ImageViews. (Not really difficult)

The elements should turn (with this 3D-Flip anim.: http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html) when the user is clicking on them. (I have already implemented this, too).

My idea only works for the first element in the ViewFlipper. I started to inflate this first view, but the new element doesn`t flip.

Is it possible to "clone/copy" the first view with its onclick events, so that the second view is flipping, too?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best and simplest solution is here:
https://github.com/genzeb/flip

Use the flip transition in any of your ViewAnimator (such as ViewFipper) by doing:

AnimationFactory.flipTransition(viewFlipper, FlipDirection.LEFT_RIGHT);

Answer (score 1):

You can use this as a sample, here's a object animator. :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:propertyName="rotationY"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="360" >
    </objectAnimator>
```

I have noticed that some tutorial states only valueTo. That will allow you to flip only once since your view is already on 360 it won't flip anymore so always use valueFrom as well. And here's the code that will flip any view:

```
    public static void flip(Context context, View view) {
    ObjectAnimator anim = (ObjectAnimator) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(
            context, R.animator.flip);
    anim.setTarget(view);
    anim.setDuration(1000);
    anim.end();
    anim.start();
}
```

Comment: yes, it works. nice job!  when it turns, the back of the view should be another view. i tried your example with 2 flip animators :the first one from 0 to 90 and the other one from 90 to 180. The first view turns with the first animator and the "backView" turs with the second animator. I placed the 2nd void at the bottom of the first and it doesn`t work.

Comment: Why not try adding AnimatorListener and start second animation when first one ends. You can't just call another animation in new line,  I reckon that's wjat you are doing.

Comment: anim.addListener(new AnimatorListener(){...});

Comment: ah I see. I was looking for setAnimationListner... so I can`t find it.